# finding using re in python the internal links in the wikipedia dump

Tags: python, regex, wikipedia

the sample in the text from the dump is -

```
s='[[Pierre-Joseph Proudhon|Proudhon]], [[Peter Kropotkin|Kropotkin]], [[Mikhail Bakunin|Bakunin]]'
```

when I run the regexp given as -

```
match_internal=re.findall('\[\[(.+)\]\]',s)
for i in match_internal:
    print i
>>Pierre-Joseph Proudhon|Proudhon]], [[Peter Kropotkin|Kropotkin]], [[Mikhail Bakunin|Bakunin
```

Rather than printing

```
Pierre-Joseph Proudhon|Proudhon
Peter Kropotkin|Kropotkin
Mikhail Bakunin|Bakunin
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use *reluctant quantifier* instead of *greedy one*: -

```
re.findall('\[\[(.+?)\]\]',s)  // Replaced `.+` with `.+?`
```

With *greedy quantifier* - your pattern - `(.+)` will match all the string till the last `]]`, and with *reluctant quantifier* - pattern - `(.+?)` will stop at the first `]]`.

```
>>> match_internal=re.findall('\[\[(.+?)\]\]',s)
>>> for i in match_internal:
        print i

Pierre-Joseph Proudhon|Proudhon
Peter Kropotkin|Kropotkin
Mikhail Bakunin|Bakunin
```

Comment: But just for the info regexp are supposed to stop whenever they see a match to the expression given as the pattern.. why the confusion regarding the greedy approach here then?

Comment: @minocha.. In Regex, quantifiers are by default greedy, in the sense that, they will try to match as much string as possible, that allows the remaining string to satisfying the following pattern. It will make sure that the pattern matches the string.

Comment: @minocha.. However, you can make those quantifier `non-greedy` or `reluctant`, by adding an extra `?` after them. So, `.+` becomes `.+?`, in which case, they will match the string till the first occurrence of the character matching the following pattern. So, `.+?[a-zA-Z]` will match the string till the first alphabet is found. And `.+[a-zA-Z]` will the match the string till the last alphabet in the string.

Answer (score 1):

The `+` quantifier matches as much as possible by default. And since the `.` matches all characters in your string, there is only a single match, excluding only the outermost brackets.

You should search for "non-bracket" characters inside the brackets like this:

```
re.findall('\[\[([^\]]+)\]\]', s)
```

Comment: while i generally agree with this approach, as using a `.` is dangerous sometimes, it seems that the data the OP is using might include single brackets because his groups are closed with double brackets, in this case, it might not be good enough.

Comment: @InbarRose is right, there might be an external link within the double  square brackets which might be represented by text enclosed within single square brackets in the wiki dump.. in that case it might not work..